# Does OpenLayers3 support WKT format?

Tags: well-known-text, openlayers

How can i show spatial data(Point, LineString,Polygon) on bing map using openlayer3?

Answer (score 3):

*OpenLayers3 Beta 4* did not not support WKT parsing as pointed out by a developer here (March 27 2014), even though it is present in [the docs](http://ol3js.org/en/v3.0.0-beta.1/apidoc/ol.parser.WKT.html): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/uRB-NaipzqQ

**Update:** It does support WKT now, as ThomasG77 pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

**An update to the answer**

Nowadays, OpenLayers 3 support WKT whereas as pointed by @chrki it wasn't possible before.

See [the API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.format.WKT.html) and [the WKT demo in action](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/wkt.html) from the official samples.